# How to export devexpress report into pdf in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

```
public ActionResult PrintReprtForSpecicDates(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/myreport.html");
        ViewBag.SpecificReport = path;
        using (ProDbDataContext _Context = new ProDbDataContext())
        {
            List<Sp_GetSpecificRecordResult> RecordList = _Context.Sp_GetSpecificRecord(startdate,enddate).ToList();
            foreach (var item in RecordList)
            {
                item.ImagePath = "/ProductsImages/" + item.ImagePath;
            }
            var dt = Helper.Helper.ToDataTable(RecordList);
            RptGetSpecificRecords reportobj = new RptGetSpecificRecords();
            reportobj.DataSource = dt;
            reportobj.Parameters["Startdate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate).ToShortDateString();
            reportobj.Parameters["Enddate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate).ToShortDateString();
            reportobj.ExportToPdf(path);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

> How i have to do next? i have export to html but now want to export to pdf guide me how to do next?

Comment: Related issue: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T313265/export-xtrareport-directly-to-pdf-on-same-page-in-mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public ActionResult PrintReprtForSpecicDates(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
    {
        using (ProDbDataContext _Context = new ProDbDataContext())
        {
            List<Sp_GetSpecificRecordResult> RecordList = _Context.Sp_GetSpecificRecord(startdate,enddate).ToList();
            var dt = Helper.Helper.ToDataTable(RecordList);
            RptGetSpecificRecords reportobj = new RptGetSpecificRecords();
            reportobj.DataSource = dt;
            reportobj.Parameters["Startdate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate).ToShortDateString();
            reportobj.Parameters["Enddate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate).ToShortDateString();
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            reportobj.ExportToPdf(stream);
            return File(stream.GetBuffer(), "application/pdf");
        }
    }
```